# Tor Unexpectedly Exited (Windows 10)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I don't know why this is happening and I can be sure that it's not Windows Defender because Disk C is excluded so it can't do anything. I've tried resetting my PC and nothing have changed, I think I've tried everything, could someone help me out there?

```
5/10/21, 01:00:35.595 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
5/10/21, 01:00:35.595 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
5/10/21, 01:00:35.595 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
5/10/21, 01:00:35.595 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
5/10/21, 01:00:35.596 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
5/10/21, 01:00:35.705 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
5/10/21, 01:00:37.911 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay
5/10/21, 01:00:38.111 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay
5/10/21, 01:00:38.666 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15% (handshake_done): Handshake with a relay done
5/10/21, 01:00:38.666 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20% (onehop_create): Establishing an encrypted directory connection
5/10/21, 01:00:39.135 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25% (requesting_status): Asking for networkstatus consensus
5/10/21, 01:00:39.412 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 30% (loading_status): Loading networkstatus consensus
```

[image: This is the problem]

Answer (score 0):

Are you still running into this issue with the latest version of Tor Browser (10.5.5)?

If yes, it would be immensely helpful if you can find any lines beginning with `[WARN]` in your Tor logs.